# Getting foreign key name through multiple relationships in Laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to get a foreign key name through a relationship of multiple foreign key names in my Laravel blade view, but it isn't bringing back the foreign key name and giving me a "Trying to get property 'location' of non-object

In my blade view I am trying to get the foreign key name like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $document->office->location->location_name }}" disabled>
```

This is my document model:

```
class Document extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
      'doc_code',
      'doc_name',
      'doc_description',
      'office_id',
    ];

    public function office() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Office::class);
    }
}
```

This is my office model:

```
class Office extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
      'location_id',
      'office_name',
    ];

    public function location() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
}
```

This is my location model:

```
class Location extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
      'location_name',
      'location_address',
    ];

}
```

This is the code for my view in my Document Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $office = Office::all();
        $document = Document::find($id);

        return view('documents.show',compact('document', 'office'));
    }
```

What am I missing in order to retrieve the foreign key name based on another foreign key like the above?

Comment: is `id` your primary key?? and make sure you have value in db.

Comment: Yes,    id 
 is my document primary key. There values are in the database.